# Find the department block number having maximum number of departments

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

To find the department block number having maximum number of departments.
I tried with my code but its not working

```
  select department_block_number
  from department
  where department_id in (select max(department_id)
  from department
   group by department_block_number);
```

The above code shows output of 2 values

202

303

while the expected output is a single value of

303

Please help

Answer (score 3):

You need aggregation!

```
select department_block_number
from department
group by department_block_number
having count(*) = (select max(cnt)
                   from (select count(*) as cnt
                         from department
                         group by department_block_number
                        )  d
                  );
```

There are other ways to express this logic, but this is what you seem to be trying to do.

Comment: I agree: Although there are more esoteric, but potentially better performing, solutions, this one captures the logic in the most readable, understandable and portable way.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution of this this may be hard coded but i got testcase passed

```
select department_block_number from department 
    where department_id in (select min(count(*)) from department 
       group by department_block_number) 
          group by department_block_number;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to fulfill the requirement:

```
SQL> select * from department;

DEPARTMENT_ID DEPARTMENT_BLOCK_NUMBER
------------- -----------------------
            1                     303
            2                     303
            3                     303
            4                     303
            5                     202
            6                     202

    -- Your Query
    SELECT
        DEPARTMENT_BLOCK_NUMBER,
        COUNT(1)
    FROM
        DEPARTMENT
    GROUP BY
        DEPARTMENT_BLOCK_NUMBER
    ORDER BY
        2 DESC NULLS LAST
    FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

**Result of the query:**

```
DEPARTMENT_BLOCK_NUMBER   COUNT(1)
----------------------- ----------
                    303          4
```

You can remove count column as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks! but Is it possible to implement the solution with the help of subqueries because the above solution is not based on subqueries?

Comment: If you really want the subqueries then answer of Gordon Linoff is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Write a query to display the block number in which the maximum number of departments is located.

```
select department_block_number 
from department where 
department_id in (
    select max(count(department_id)) 
    from depratment
    group by department_id
)
group by department_block_number;
```